# onChange not working on the first input into the text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

onChange event doesn't return the first change of the text input but works on subsequent changes. Sorry if this is obvious, I'm new to React.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 

function Header() {

    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");

    function handleChange(event) {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }

    // when submit button clicked, current state of the text input is stored inside location constant 
    function handleClick() {
        setLocation(text);
        const geoCoderURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + location + "&limit=5&appid={apikey}"
        function getCoordinates(url) {
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                const locationLat = response.data[0].lat;
                const locationLon = response.data[0].lon;
                
            });
        } 
        getCoordinates(geoCoderURL);        
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Five Day Forecast</h1> 
            <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name"autoFocus placeholder="Enter location here."/>
            <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>Forecast</button> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setLocation(text);`, `handleClick` will finish execution before the `location` value is actually updated.

There is no need for `location` and `setLocation`; looks like maybe `location` is supposed to be the same as `text`.

```
function handleClick() {
    const geoCoderURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + text + "&limit=5&appid={apikey}"
    function getCoordinates(url) {
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            const locationLat = response.data[0].lat;
            const locationLon = response.data[0].lon;  
        });
    } 
    getCoordinates(geoCoderURL);        
}
```